# Loop over columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe, first to calculate the following math operation year+n/year.value==2009 for every cohort and then perform the mean for each cohort

```
df
             id                                                        
year       2009     2010     2011     2012     2013     2014     2015   
cohort                                                                  
2009.0  72092.0  60513.0  48797.0  40968.0  34919.0  30452.0  26961.0   
2010.0      NaN  73735.0  61899.0  50263.0  42184.0  36150.0  31516.0   
2011.0      NaN      NaN  76809.0  64093.0  51372.0  43277.0  36994.0   
2012.0      NaN      NaN      NaN  69776.0  57621.0  46453.0  39098.0   
2013.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  71613.0  58996.0  47657.0   
2014.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  65430.0  52540.0   
2015.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  67121.0   
2016.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
2017.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

I will show the math operation that i want to perform because my english is not good and math is a universal language :)

For whenever 1 year pass since 2009: (n=1)

first value needed = ((60513.0/72092.0) + (61899.0/73735.0) + (64093.0+76809.0) + (57621.0/69776.0) + (58996.0+71613.0) + (52540.0/65430.0))/6

For whenever 2 year pass since 2009: (n=2)

second value needed = ((48797.0/72092.0) + (50263.0/73735.0) + (51372.0/76809.0) + (46453.0/69776.0) + (47657.0/71613.0))/5

For whenever 3 year pass since 2009: (n=3) (Last one, i think with this one the looping of what i want to do will be understand)

third value needed = ((40968.0/72092.0) + (42184.0/73735.0) + (43277.0/76809.0) + (39098.0/69776.0))/4

And so on until the last value would be

last value = 26961.0/72092.0

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

I am trying somethin like this, maybe it can help

First value:

```
((df1.iloc[0,1]/df1.iloc[0,0]) + (df1.iloc[1,2]/df1.iloc[1,1]) + 
(df1.iloc[2,3]/df1.iloc[2,2]) + (df1.iloc[3,4]/df1.iloc[3,3]) + 
(df1.iloc[4,5]/df1.iloc[4,4]) + (df1.iloc[5,6]/df1.iloc[5,5]))/6
```

Second value:

```
((df1.iloc[0,2]/df1.iloc[0,0]) + (df1.iloc[1,3]/df1.iloc[1,1]) + 
(df1.iloc[2,4]/df1.iloc[2,2]) + (df1.iloc[3,5]/df1.iloc[3,3]) + 
(df1.iloc[4,6]/df1.iloc[4,4]))/5
```

Third value:

```
((df1.iloc[0,3]/df1.iloc[0,0]) + (df1.iloc[1,4]/df1.iloc[1,1]) + 
(df1.iloc[2,5]/df1.iloc[2,2]) + (df1.iloc[3,6]/df1.iloc[3,3]))/4
```

And so on...

Something like this but with a loop it is the code which i am looking for.

Comment: Can you please print `df.to_dict()` and paste it in your question? Otherwise, it becomes hard to reproduce this dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, we need Shift `NaN`s to the bottom of their row., then do `div` and `mean`

```
df=df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull), 1)
df.iloc[:,1:].div(df.iloc[:,0],0).mean(0)
Out[36]: 
2010    0.827654
2011    0.671719
2012    0.566037
2013    0.485424
2014    0.424914
2015    0.373980
```

More info

```
df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull), 1)
Out[37]: 
           2009     2010     2011     2012     2013     2014     2015
2009.0  72092.0  60513.0  48797.0  40968.0  34919.0  30452.0  26961.0
2010.0  73735.0  61899.0  50263.0  42184.0  36150.0  31516.0      NaN
2011.0  76809.0  64093.0  51372.0  43277.0  36994.0      NaN      NaN
2012.0  69776.0  57621.0  46453.0  39098.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
2013.0  71613.0  58996.0  47657.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2014.0  65430.0  52540.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2015.0  67121.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2016.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2017.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot! i have another question similar to this one if u can help me. What if i want to sum all the values for the differents rows and then make the proportion of the first/second/third/etc values of row "n" over the sum of the row. It is possible?

Comment: @LucasDresl yes we can,  you can look at `cumsum(1)`  and div, I think this will achieve your expect out put

Comment: I just used `df1.iloc[:,:]/df1.iloc[0,:].sum()` and i think it works

Comment: I think it is not correct, because divides all the values by the sum of the first row. When i want to divided each element row by the sum of his corresponding row :( @Wen

Comment: @LucasDresl can you show me you out put ? or maybe let us open a new question :-)